# Use return() for early return

Tags: r

I read an R style guide here: https://style.tidyverse.org/functions.html#naming

They wrote in Section 3.3:

> **Only** use return() for early returns. Otherwise, rely on R to return the result of the last evaluated expression.

I usually use `return()` at the end of my own functions and I don't see if there is a problem. I don't understand why they advise that we only use `return()` for early returns. Is it important or just a convention for their style guide?

Comment: It is a matter of style and convention in R coding.  Since there is an implicit `return` of the last value in a function, the convention is to omit an explicit call to `return`, that is all.  You may use it for early returns or if, for some reason, it would not be obvious which value is being returned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, please post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker I felt that the answer was sort of already contained within the documentation, and so there was not much more I could add beyond a comment.

Comment: I think this  is a reasonably good question and your comment *is* the answer, so it might as well be posted as an answer ...

Comment: Or vote to close the question as opinion based because that's pretty much all style guides are anyway -- just strong opinions on how code should be formatted.